# Dynamically created modal to display rss feed from wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For a project im trying to display group diaries onto our website. instead of just rewriting the code over and over again to add the new entries i thought through a JS script i could reed them into a twitter.bootstrap modal.A modal is a javascript pop up window. but im having problems it creates my buttons and brings in data but all my buttons point to the same data.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url      : document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('https://algorithmsdatastructurestoolga1.wordpress.com/category/nicholas-judd-blog/feed/'),
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function (data) {
        if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
            $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
                var button='<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">'+e.title+'</button>&nbsp;';
                document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML += '<ul class="list-group">' + '<li>' + button + '<li>' ;
                document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML += '</ul>';
                document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML += '<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby=basicModal" aria-hidden="true">'+
                            '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                                '<div class="modal-content">'+
                                    '<div class="modal-header">'+
                                        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'+
                                        '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">'+e.title+'</h4>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="modal-body">'+
                                        '<h3>'+e.content+'</h3>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>';
            });
        }
    }
});
```

i know its got to do with data target in button and id in the div class but i cant work out how to change this dynamically.

Also im looking for help in finding the answer not nessicarly just being given the answer.

p.s. im brand new to websites how ever i am a 3rd year computer science student.

Comment: What exactly is a _modal_? Do you mean a _model_? Your question could use some proofreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand of your script you're requesting an AJAX call that returns an object containing several "feed" entries. For each entry, you want to insert a button into a `<div id="feed"></div>` and button that toggles a unique modal that contains that entry.

The problem here is that all your modals share the same ID (#basicModal), and all your buttons target the same id. You need to create a different id for each modal.

Here's how:

```
if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
    var uniqueIndex = 0;
    $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
        uniqueIndex++;
        var uniqueID = "basicModal" + uniqueIndex;
        var button='<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#' + uniqueID + '">'+e.title+'</button>&nbsp;';
        document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML += '<ul class="list-group">' + '<li>' + button + '<li>' ;
        document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML += '</ul>';
        document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML += '<div class="modal fade" id="' + uniqueID + '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby=basicModal" aria-hidden="true">'+
        '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
        '<div class="modal-content">'+
        '<div class="modal-header">'+
        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'+
        '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">'+e.title+'</h4>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="modal-body">'+
        '<h3>'+e.content+'</h3>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="modal-footer">'+
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';
    });
}
```

Assuming your HTML is formatted properly, I think that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks your a life saver